# I want to submit data to bigquery using cloud dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

```
T,WeekCodeOption,TimeWidthSEQ,StationCode,RealBroadcastMinutes,StandardTargetFlag,TargetInfoCode,Rate,ExcludeDates
"{'TFrom': '20230213', 'TTo': '20230213'}",11,1,1,1440,"['1', '1', '1', '1']","['101', '102', '103', '104']","{'101': ['3.2'], '102': ['1.9'], '103': ['1.6'], '104': ['2.6']}",
```

I have the above csv format in cloud storage.

I want to put it into a bigquery table.

However, I get the following error.

I understand that the reason for this error is that the term key cannot be found, but I don't know how to change the data in that case.

Is there any way to avoid the error?

The following is the code we are testing.

```
import logging
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import json

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import WriteToBigQuery, BigQueryDisposition
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions

TZ_JST = timezone(timedelta(hours=9))


class BeamOptions:
    def __init__(self, runner):
        self.options = PipelineOptions()
        # GoogleCloud Option
        self.gcloud_options = self.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
        self.gcloud_options.job_name = "dataflow-job"
        self.gcloud_options.project = "xxx"
        self.gcloud_options.temp_location = "gs://output/tmp2"
        self.gcloud_options.region = "us-central1"
        # Setup Option
        self.options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
        # Standard Option
        self.options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = runner


def parse_file(element):
    for line in csv.reader(
        [element],
        quotechar='"',
        delimiter=",",
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
        skipinitialspace=True,
    ):
        return line


def convert_dict(element):
    now_utc = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    now = datetime.now(TZ_JST)
    #term = json.loads(element[0].replace("'", '"'))
    return {
        "T": element[0],
        "WeekCodeOption": element[1],
        "TimeWidthSEQ": element[2],
        "StationCode": element[3],
        "RealBroadcastMinutes": element[4],
        "StandardTargetFlag": element[5],
        "TargetInfoCode": element[6],
        "Rate": element[7],
        "ExcludeDates": element[8],
        "created_time_ts_utc": now_utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"),
        "created_time_dt_jst": now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"),
    }


def run(gcs_uri, table_spec, runner):
    options = PipelineOptions(
        runner="DataflowRunner",
        project="xxxxxx",
        temp_location="gs://output/tmp2",
        staging_location="gs://output/stg",
        region="us-central1",
        setup_file="./setup.py",
    # other options
    )

    with beam.Pipeline(options=BeamOptions(runner).options) as p:
        raw_datas = p | "Read from GCS" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(gcs_uri)
        tran_datas = (
            raw_datas
            | "transform csv" >> beam.Map(parse_file)
            | "transform dict" >> beam.Map(convert_dict)
        )
        tran_datas | "Write to BigQuery" >> WriteToBigQuery(
            table_spec,
            create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
            write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
        )
schema = 'Term:STRING, WeekCodeOption:INTEGER, TimeWidthSEQ:INTEGER, StationCode:INTEGER, RealBroadcastMinutes:INTEGER, StandardTargetFlag:STRING, TargetInfoCode:STRING, Rate:STRING, ExcludeDates:STRING'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(
        "gs://input/df.csv", 
        "dataset.dataflow",
        "DataflowRunner",  
    )
```

I expected csv data to be submitted to bigquery.

Comment: Could you mention what error you're getting?

Comment: I resolved this issue.